# Computer broke, how to obtain the private key?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery

I tried to install Bitcoin Core on my PC. The synchronization was not completed when my computer crashed. I am unable to restart it.

I had bitcoins in the wallet already. I have the Bitcoin address but I don't have the private key that can make the funds spendable. How can I obtain this private key to move the bitcoins to another wallet without having to repair my computer?

Comment: Just to make sure: I understood that your computer is not working anymore, and Jonas seems to have understood that Bitcoin Core isn't starting anymore. What is it that you're unable to restart?

Comment: Just for anyone else seeing this question, and this is very important: Do not do anything but make a complete backup image (byte by byte, not file by file) of the hard drive. The keys might be on the hard drive but any changes you make (even booting up the system, or trying to) might damage them. If things do not go well, you need to be able to get back to exactly where you are  to try a different technique.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, backup your **wallet.dat** file (if you don't know where it is stored, check this: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory)
2. Analyse the crash, read the error message.
3. Quit Bitcoin-Core, try to **temporarily** move your data-directoy and let bitcoin-core create a new one.
4. Quit Bitcoin-Core, replace the newly created wallet.dat file with your old one (after you made a backup)
5. Start Bitcoin-Core again
6. If you don't want to wait until your full-node is synced (can take a couple of days), export your private key by opening the Development Console (ctrl - D in 0.13.0) and type `dumpwallet <path + filename>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that your computer doesn't start anymore, you will probably want to extract the hard drive and try to access it from another computer.